# Multifunctional getter for php class

Tags: php, php-7.2

I wrote some kind of safe class that receives `stdClass` type content:

```
class SafeContent extends stdClass {
​
    /** @var stdClass $content */
    protected $content;
​
    public function __construct(stdClass $content) {
        $this->content = $content;
    }
​
    public function __get($name) {
        if ($this->content->name == null) {
             // do something
        }
    }
​
}
```

and I want `SafeContent`'s getter to catch get operations like `$safeContent->someField->anotherField->lastField`, so the `name` argument in `__get` will be `someField->anotherField->lastField` or something like that. Is there a way to manage this ?

Comment: You don't really need to extend `stdClass`; that's already implicit by the fact that it's a class.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get all fields in one `__get` with one argument, but you can cast each object to your `SafeContent` class, so every sequential call will enter in your class' getter:

```
// inside __get function
if (!isset($this->content->$name) || $this->content->$name == null) {
    // do something, probably throw an exception
}

if ($this->content->$name instanceof stdClass) {
    // return the instance of your class with appropriate content
    $component = new self($this->content->$name);
    return $component;
}

return $this->content->$name;
```